# Regular expressions for password validation

Tags: regex

I need to validate a password that matches the following criteria:

- minimum 8 characters
- contain a combination of numbers and letters
- must not enforce special characters

The follow regular expression is what I came up with:

```
^{8,}.(?=*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])&
```

but this is failing on:

- !password1
- password1
- Password1

From what I can gather, trying to investigate RegEx, `{8,}` means minimum of 8 and don't care about the maximum, `\d` specifies digits, whitespaces and special characters. The a-z makes sense.

Comment: What is the ampersand supposed to be doing? Did you mean `$`?

Comment: Although it's probably possible, regular expressions don't seem like a very nice way to approach this problem. Do you need to use them, or would you consider a non-regex solution? (Though we'd need to know what language you're working in.)

Comment: @JadedEric, I can wholeheartedly recommend a development environment where you can test your regular expressions live, such as [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm).

Comment: @bzlm, I like http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ - it works online or you can download a desktop Adobe Air app.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,}$
```

[See it @work](http://www.rubular.com/r/SD15O51jbX)

Comment: I had this one, got it off a web site but it didn't work. Found out that our Membership Provider was also limiting the characters :$. Feel like a graduate developer right now. Thanks.

Comment: Well, I'll delete my "answer" then. Good for you :D

Comment: @JadedEric could you please explain what `?=.*` means? or just `?=` ... I know that `a?` allows an `a` or no `a`. Just don't know what the `question mark (?)` does when you put an `equals (=)` behind it.

Answer (score -1):

simple not most efficient way:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9!.-_]{8,}$
```

Replace `!.-_` with the list of special characters you'd like to allow

Comment: @NullUserException What do you mean? OP is asking for a regex to verify passwords so I don't understand what you mean with 'this allows password'.

Comment: @WilliamD.Edwards The answer provided here would allow `password` to validate, violating the conditions of the original problem.