# Password validation php regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm new to regex.
I need to validate passwords using php with following password policy using Regex:

Passwords:

1. Must have minimum 8 characters
2. Must have 2 numbers
3. Symbols allowed are : `! @ # $ % *`

I have tried the following:   `/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%]$/`

Comment: Can you possibly post here the regexp [you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and isn't working?

Comment: @NullPoiиteя Please read the question Null

Comment: Try http://regexlib.com/

Comment: The `Symbols allowed are : ! @ # $ % *` part bothers me. Why are you only allowing certain symbols? You should allow the entire character set since you're passing the password off to a library like bcrypt anyways which will produce a hash. You ARE basing your passwords, right?

Comment: Previous questions with quite similar content are e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615078/regex-for-password-requirements and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245267/regular-expressions-for-password-validation ... Note also the many "for the love of `$dmr`, don't do that" comments.

Comment: @RyanKearney Allowing only those symbols is part of application requirement.

Comment: @sash What about hindu, hebrew, arabic letters or digits ?

Comment: See [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345922/reference-password-validation/48346033#48346033)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following matches exactly your requirements: `^(?=.*\d.*\d)[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%*]{8,}$`

[**Online demo**](http://regex101.com/r/fD5lN6) <sub>`<<< You don't need the modifiers, they are just there for testing purposes.`</sub>

**Explanation**

- `^` : match begin of string
- `(?=.*\d.*\d)` : positive lookahead, check if there are 2 digits
- `[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%*]{8,}` : match digits, letters and `!@#$%*` 8 or more times
- `$` : match end of string

Answer (score 0):

I would first try and find two numbers, using non-regex (or `preg_match_all('[0-9]', ...) >= 2`, then validating against:

`^[!@#$%*a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}$`

This should be faster and easier to understand. To do it using only regex sounds you need lookahead which basically scans the expression twice afaik, though I'm not sure of the PHP internals on that one.

Be prepared for a lot of complaints about passwords not being accepted. I personally have a large subset of passwords that wouldn't validate against those restrictions. Also nonsensical passwords like `12345678` would validate, or even `11111111`, but not `f4#f@faASvCXZr$%%zcorrecthorsebatterystaple`.

Answer (score 0):

Full Strong Password Validation With PHP

- Min 8 chars long
- Min One Digit
- Min One Uppercase
- Min One Lower Case
- Min One Special Chars

`/^\S*(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=\S*[\W])[a-zA-Z\d]{8,}\S*$/`

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/ow6hrf/1)

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick. Look ahead is nice for this...

```
//Matches alphanumeric or specified special characters and requires at least 2 digits

/^(?=.*\d.*\d)[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%]{4,20}$/
```

*BONUS* requires one of each: uppercase, lowercase, digit, and specified special characters

```
 /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%])[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%]{4,20}$/
```

**EXPLAINED in pieces below**

Look ahead/require for a lower case:

```
(?=.*[a-z])
```

Look ahead/require an uppercase:

```
(?=.*[A-Z])
```

Look ahead/require two digit:

```
(?=.*\d.*\d)
```

Look ahead/require only specified special chars:

```
(?=.*[!@#$%])
```

Entire password must contain a minimum of 4 and maximum of 20 only alpha numeric and specified special chars:

```
[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%]{4,20}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if(preg_match('/[!@#$%*a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}/',$password) && preg_match_all('/[0-9]/',$password) >= 2)
{
    // do
}
```