# Regex for password match

Tags: regex

I am using regex pattern match for passwords. 
There are only three constrains on my password. 
1. There must be at least 1 UPPER-CHARACTER.
2. There must be at least 1 special char from given list.
3. There must be at least 8 characters length.

I used this regex : `[!@#\$%\^\&*?+=._-]{1,}[a-z0-9]{6,}[A-Z]{1,}$`.
but it matters sequence. Sequence must not matter at all. Any Idea?

Comment: Without regex: you could iterate over the string, match every character with you criteria, toggle a flag for each one, and check if all of your flags are true after the iteration.

Comment: I just used online tool for test. http://regexpal.com/

Comment: This thread has some suggestions with explanations:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491670/regular-expression-for-password-at-least-2-digits-and-one-special-character-and

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following regex should work:

```
^(?=.*[!@#\$%\^\&*?+=._-])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Impressive visualization, can you please share how you created it?

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}$
```

This should work.

Comment: This doesn't check for special characters, doesn't it?

Comment: Oh, yes. Forgot about it. you can add (?=.*[the characters you want])

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would go with:

```
(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*[!#\$%&\?])^\D.{7}
```

Note that the `.*` after each look-ahead term was superfluous.

`(?!...)` is a negative look-ahead, to make sure there are no special characters.

`^\D` requires that the first character be a non-digit. Then I simply require 7 characters after that, because the end is not enforced.

But why exclude special characters from passwords? Usually just the opposite is encouraged.

Comment: This doesn't match with "a1Aaaaa!12tza" (and any other combination I tried...)