# PHP Regex - Must contain at least any 2 letters in UTF-8

Tags: php, regex, string, utf-8

Right now, i'm trying to create a PHP Regular Expression with these following conditions:

- Accepts all UTF-8 characters
- Space between words are allowed, how only 1 space and not multiple.
- Allow all symbols for example: !#$%^&*()_-={}[] except: "@"
- No trailing spaces after or before the string.
- Range should be 2-16 characters including spaces
- And must contain at least 2 letter characters in the string.

Here is the Regex I have drawn up so far:

`/^(?=.{2,16}$)[^@\s]+(?:\h[^@\s]+)*$/um`

So far this does all of the following except that it doesn't meet the last condition which is that it must contain at least 2 letters. For example:

`"..He" //should be true`

`"He$*" //should be true`

`".." //should be false`

`"*%" //should be false`

`"!#$%^&*()" //should be false since there is no letters`

`"$$tonyMoney™" //should be true`

`"أنا أحب جا™" //should be true`

`"To" //should be true`

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: is this used for validating username ??

Comment: Does that matter @Andrew?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression for password (at least 2 digits and one special character and minimum length 8)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491670/regular-expression-for-password-at-least-2-digits-and-one-special-character-and)

Comment: @JayBlanchard no....just out of curiosity, I aint regex expert :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually use

```
/^(?![^@]*@)(?!.*\s\s)(?=(?:\P{L}*\p{L}){2})\S.{0,14}\S$/us
```

Here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aB2rZ9/1) (modified a bit for a demo with multiline text).

For the regex to work with Unicode strings, you need to specify the `/u` modifier. For the `.` to match any character, you need to use `/s` modifier.

The regex breakdown:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?![^@]*@)` - make sure there is no `@` in the string
- `(?!.*\s\s)` - make sure there are no 2 consecutive whitespaces
- `(?=(?:\P{L}*\p{L}){2})` - make sure **there is at least 2 Unicode letters**
- `\S.{0,14}\S` - 2 symbols are obligatory, must start and end with a non-whitespace, from 2 to 16 characters long
- `$` - end of string

Comment: Note that `"أنا أحب جافا سكريبت™"` is longer than 16 symbols.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: True, have not thought about that. Fixed.