# Figuring out regex for the mentioned condition

Tags: java, regex, string

I came across the concept of `regex` recently and was poised to solve the problem using just the `regex` inside `matches()` and `length()` method of `String` class. The problem was related to **password matching**.Here are the three conditions that need to be considered:

- A password must have at least eight characters.
- A password consists of only letters and digits.
- A password must contain at least two digits.

I was able to do this problem by using various other `String` and `Character` class methods but I need **to do them only by** `regex`.What I have tried helps me with most of the test cases but some of them(test cases) are still failing.Since, I am learning `regex` implementation so please help me with what I am missing or doing wrong. Below is what I tried:

```
public class CheckPassword {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your password:\n");
        String str1 = sc.next();
        //String dig2 = "\\d{2}";
        //String letter = ".*[A-Z].*";
        //String letter1 = ".*[a-z].*";
        //if(str1.length() >= 8 && str1.matches(dig2) &&(str1.matches(letter) || str1.matches(letter1)) )
          if(str1.length() >= 8 && str1.matches("^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\\d{2,})(?=.*[0-9])[A-Z0-9a-z]+$"))
               System.out.println("Valid Password");
          else
               System.out.println("Invalid Password");

}
}
```

**EDIT**

**Okay So I figured out the first and second case just I am having problem in appending the third case with them i.e. contains at least 2 digits.**

```
 if(str1.length() >= 8 && str1.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]*")) 
//works exclusive of the third criterion
```

Comment: How about `[a-zA-Z0-9]*[0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*[0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*`. There might be a better way, but this matches any alphanumeric string that must contain at least 2 digits.

Comment: No sir; it is failing for this test case `manujsan12`

Comment: Look here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491670/regular-expression-for-password-at-least-2-digits-and-one-special-character-and

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay Thank you @TDG and M.Aroosi for giving your precious time. I have figured out the solution and this solution satisfies all cases

```
 // answer edited based on OP's working comment.
 String dig2 =  "^(?=.*?\\d.*\\d)[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}$";
 if(str1.matches(dig2))
      {
       //body          
      }
```

Comment: The `"^(?=.*?\\d.*\\d)[a-zA-Z0-9]$"` is a wrong pattern. It will never match any string.

Comment: Okay Sir; but I think it satisfies all test cases!!!!But since I am a tyro in it.so please explain any case which fails or why it is a wrong pattern please explain?

Comment: Just see my answer with a correct expression already explained. Also, here is [my regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/O0kzIE/1).

Comment: See [your regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VaNiEb/1). It does not match anything.

Comment: It is matching sir;I think you forgot to use `str1.length() >= 8`.By the way thanks sir for that online regex checker

Comment: Sir I mentioned that I am a newbie in regex so I don't know this part `{8,}` that is why I used `length()` function

Comment: As for `{8,}`, see [this reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit).

Comment: Okay Sir thanks!!!So now if I change my regex by adding `{8,}` it satisfies all the cases on the website mentioned by you: https://regex101.com/ So now is it correct `"^(?=.*?\\d.*\\d)[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}$"`?

Comment: Yes, but it is less efficient than mine (mine and yours do the same thing now). Besides, yours contain redundant `^` and `$`.

Comment: Thank you sir for the same and I'm still learning and it's one of your forte so it should and must be efficient...

Answer (score 1):

You may actually use a single regex inside `matches()` to validate all 3 conditions:

- *A password must have at least eight characters*  and
- *A password consists of only letters and digits* - use `\p{Alnum}{8,}` in the consuming part
- *A password must contain at least two digits* - use the `(?=(?:[a-zA-Z]*\d){2})` positive lookahead anchored at the start

Combining all three:

```
.matches("(?=(?:[a-zA-Z]*\\d){2})\\p{Alnum}{8,}")
```

Since `matches()` method anchors the pattern by default (i.e. it requires a full string match) no `^` and `$` anchors are necessary.

**Details**

- `^` - implicit in `matches()` - start of string
- `(?=(?:[a-zA-Z]*\d){2})` - a positive lookahead (`(?=...)`) that requires the presence of exactly two sequences of:

  - `[a-zA-Z]*` - zero or more  ASCII letters
  - `\d` - an ASCII digit
- `\p{Alnum}{8,}` - 8 or more alphanumeric chars (ASCII only)
- `$` - implicit in `matches()` - end of string.

Comment: The [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/O0kzIE/1) (`\p{Alnum}` is changed into an equivalent `[[:alnum:]]` since PCRE does not support the `\p{Alnum}` notation).

Comment: Sir with due respect I have tried your solution but this test case fails `dqwdnwkdnqkdqk12dwnwkcnwkcwk ndknqwkdn`

Comment: @Mandy8055 And what do you expect? It contains a space, your requirements do not allow spaces in the string. Remove the space - [and it will get matched](https://regex101.com/r/O0kzIE/2).

Comment: Okay Sir there must have been some confusion. But I mnetioned that it must contain **only letters and digits**

Comment: Sir your answer is important to me.please mention how to get rid of that `white space` problem?

Comment: @Mandy8055 What problem? Your question is how to validate a string that is made of letters and/or digits, right? Or is it about *sanitizing*, i.e. removing all chars other than those allowed *and* validation? You may remove all non-allowed chars with `.replaceAll("\\P{Alnum}+", "")`.